# StripeElementPayment Vue2 adding address element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, stripe-payments

Hello im trying to add address for already working stripe payment solution, created with vuestripe.com solution, but I cannot fid a way how to implement that.

Somehow it should work with https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element, but here: https://vuestripe.com/stripe-elements/payment, or here https://docs.vuestripe.com/vue-stripe/stripe-elements/payment I can't find anything usefull.

At least something like a custom field for name and address would help.

Implementing basic stripe payment element is simple, i have it like this:

```
<stripe-element-payment
    ref="paymentRef"
    :pk="stripePk"
    :elements-options="elementsOptions"
    :confirm-params="confirmParams"
    @element-ready="stripeElementReady"
    @element-change="stripeElementChange"
    @loading="loaderVisible = true"
    @error="stripeError"
/>
```

with elementOptions just with styles

```
elementsOptions: {
                clientSecret: this.clientSecret,
                locale: this.$i18n.locales.filter(i => i.code === this.$i18n.locale)[0].code,
                appearance: {
                    theme: 'stripe',
                    variables: {
                        colorPrimary: '#0570de',
                        colorBackground: '#ffffff',
                        colorText: '#282828',
                        colorDanger: '#df1b41',
                        spacingUnit: '4px',
                        spacingGridRow: '16px',
                        borderRadius: '20px',
                        // See all possible variables below
                    },
                    rules: {
                        '.Label': {
                            color: '#7C7C7C',
                            marginBottom: '9px'
                        },
                        '.Input': {
                            paddingLeft: '20px'
                        }
                    }
                } // appearance options
            },
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: "#"
            }
```

thank you

Comment: Looks like the `vue-stripe` library does not yet support the Address Element. Looks like it's currently being built according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vue-stripe/vue-stripe/issues/339).